# Serial by Parallel Booth Multiplier

Tags: routes, fpga, multiplication, latency, carryflag

Why "[Bit serial adds eliminate need for carry chain](http://www.andraka.com/multipli.php)" ?

I do not understand why the first bit serial 2's complement block is placed ahead of the subsequent Bit serial adders ?

[image: Serial by Parallel Booth Multiplier]

Comment: http://www.andraka.com/multipli.php https://www.reddit.com/r/FPGA/comments/aiiccy/serial_by_parallel_booth_multiplier/

Answer (score 1):

> Why "Bit serial adds eliminate need for carry chain" ?

Multiplication is done by means of a set of additions and shift operations. 
Every result of an addition is used as an input the the next addition (which is called an accumulation), and the other input is the multiplier shifted by one bit.

Standard binary multiplication A*B, where B=2^n-1*b_n-i + ... + 2^1*b_1+2^0*b_0 is done by mean of the following algorithm

```
Res<=0
for i in 0 .. n-1 do
   Res <= Res + A * b_i
   A <= A * 2
done
```

In general additions require to propagate the carry from the LSB to the MSB (carry chains). But for accumulations, it is possible to use "carry save addition" and it is the standard mean to perform a multiplication. In that case, instead of feeding the output carry to the input carry of the next adder (carry chain), it is saved and used shifted in the next addition.

This way, an addition step only requires to go through one layer of adder, instead of n when carry chains are involved. Note that carry save allows to fasten internal accumulation steps, but the sum output of the adder will remain incomplete until the carry is effectively propagated.

This is what is represented in the figure. Output carry (on the bottom right) is memorized  (in the blue register) and used as an input for the next addition of this adder. Adder sum output (on the top right of each adder) is memorized and sent shifted to one input of the next adder, while the LSB that will no longer be modified is bit shifted out.

Note that left shifting in the multiplication algorithm (A<=A*2) is replaced by a right shift of the result as shown in the figure. This way neither carry, nor A require any shift.

Hence the multiplication will require n steps (one per bit in the multiplicand B), but each step can be fast as it only require the traversal of a single adder.

To be correct, the final result requires to be completely added to the carries. This can be done by a standard adder with carry chain, or by N extra bit serial addition steps with the multiplier set to zero.

> I do not understand why the first bit serial 2's complement block is placed ahead of the subsequent Bit serial adders ?

I think the figure is somehow incorrect. This schematic corresponds to unsigned multiplication. Signed multiplication require either different  steps or a data recoding (such as Booth recoding). Such a recoding is explained at the end of the page given in your link and will require at every step either and addition or a substraction, but the figure uses regular binary encoding and not 2's complement.

Comment: How is the Serial by Parallel Booth Multiplier different from Carry Save Array Multiplier ?

The blue register flip flop just keep updating the carry_out value ? How does this update help in the multiplication process when "Bit serial adds ELIMINATE need for carry chain" ?

Comment: Serial multiplier (that actually is not Booth as described) uses n full-adders and performs the computation in n clock cycles. Carry save array mult uses n\*n full adders and performs the mult in one (long) cycle. Somehow it is an unrolled version of the serial multiplier.  In the array multiplier, there is carry propagation between layers, but the carry save structure reduces the propagation time from n*n to n. And in the serial multiplier there is no carry propagation, but several cycles are required.

Comment: "in the serial multiplier there is no carry propagation" <-- If there is no carry propagation, how does the carry_out value updating mechanism through the blue register flip flop actually help in the multiplication process ?

Comment: The proper sentence should be "there is no carry propagation within a clock cycle". This is a mean to reduce clock period. But carry propagation is obviously required in the algorithm and is done between clock cycles by means of the register.

Comment: What I am trying to clarify is why the carry_out is not propagated to the rest of the full-adders in the figure ?

Comment: It is propagated in the computational next stage. It is the lower loop on the left.

Comment: I need pen and pencil to verify that the multiplier in the figure actually do multiplication correctly.  By the way, why "Routing is all nearest neighbor EXCEPT serial input which is broadcast" ? I thought the loopback update using the blue registers (ALL 4 register flip flops) requires very little routing effort by the tool ?

Comment: Initially, before any partial bit multiplication is started, the "2's C" block has a carry value of 0, this means that the loopback update mechanism of carry does not really do anything at all for the "2's C" block (the only input ports are A and C_in , where C_in is always zero). Please correct me if wrong

Comment: I am not getting the correct multiplication answer. Something is wrong with the S(um) propagation mechanism.